# re.search if/if not, but "nonetype object has no attribute 'group'"

Tags: python

I am reading through .txt files and trying to capture **Keywords:___**. Some text files have that pattern and other files do not have that pattern. Using **if* statement, I would like to extract the result or indicate "not found" if the pattern does not exist in the file. But I get

**matchcomp = re.search(r'Keywords:([^,]*)(,|$)', text1).group(1).strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'**

Please help...

```
import re,os

os.chdir('C:\Users\dul\Dropbox\Article')

def extract_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file1:
        text1=file1.read()

    if matchcomp = re.search(r'Keywords:([^,]*)(,|$)', text1).group(1).strip():
        return(matchcomp)
    else:
        return('not found')

    with open('outfile.txt', "a+") as outfile:
        outfile.write("\n"+matchcomp)

files = os.listdir("C:\Users\dul\Dropbox\Article")
for file in files:
    if ".txt" in file:
        extract_data(file)
```

Comment: The code you've pasted here raises a SyntaxError. Please try to paste your actual code again.

Answer (score 1):

`re.search` is returning `None` sometimes, so you can't then call `.group(1)` on it (as it's `None`).

You need to check the results of that search before using it.

Something like:

```
result = re.search(r'Keywords:([^,]*)(,|$)', text1)
if result is not None:
    return(result.group(1).strip())
else:
    return('not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently the (in)famous [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) added assignment expressions to python.
(Will only work in Python 3.8)
One of their uses is to make what you are trying work.
Basically replace `=` by `:=` inside expressions.  Something like:

```
if matchcomp := re.search(r'Keywords:([^,]*)(,|$)', text1) :
    return(matchcomp.group(1).strip())
else:
    return('not found')
```

See for example [PEP 572 discussion](https://lwn.net/Articles/757713/)

## Statutory (non-technical) warning

The jury is out on the benefits to python of this PEP's adoption.
However there is really no dispute that its *consequence* — the [resignation of Guido as BDFL](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/07/13/python_creator_guido_van_rossum_quits/) — is terrible for python.

Think on that when you use/enjoy this feature!

All things considered @Caboose suggestion is (IMHO) the way to go